# What's wrong with the having clause in my query?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, having

```
Select facid, sum(slots) as total
from cd.bookings 
group by facid 
having total > 1000
order by facid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a column alias in the HAVING clause, you have to repeat the expression:

```
Select facid, sum(slots) as total
from cd.bookings 
group by facid 
having sum(slots) > 1000
order by facid;
```